# contour integral in a region where the function doesn't have any poles

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

What is the value of the following contour integral? The contour is a circle with radius $0.5$ around $z=i$ point: $|z-i|<\frac{1}{2}$

$$\oint_C\frac{dz}{2-\sin z}$$

I think it is $0$ because the fuction doesn't have any singularities in $|z-i|<\frac{1}{2}$. It was a question on a multichoice exam yesterday and I chose $0$, but I suspect it may have some tricky point in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show that $\sin z$ is never equal to $2$ inside the contour. So suppose $\sin(x+iy) = \sin x \cosh y + i\cos x \sinh y$ is equal to $2$. Then we must have

$$\sin x \cosh y = 2$$
$$\cos x \sinh y = 0$$

For the second equation to hold, we must have $\cos x = 0$ or $\sinh y = 0$. But $|x| \le \frac12$ inside the contour, so $\cos x$ must be non-zero. And $y \ge \frac12$ inside the contour, so $\sinh y$ must be non-zero.

Hence $\sin z - 2$ is non-zero inside the contour, as you say.

Comment: Excuse me, right now I got access to the exam's questions, and found out that the contour is a circle with the radius of $3/2$ around the origin. Does it change the answer? I think no.

Comment: @user215721: "I think no": Argue it through!

Comment: Because in this case again $\cos x$ can not be zero because $\pi/2$ is slightly greater than 3/2. So $y=0$ and thus $\cosh y=1$ and thus $\sin z$ can not be equal to 2. Right?

Comment: @user215721: Exactly.